# How to "explode" a drop shadow into a shape in Flash?

Tags: adobe-flash, shadows

I need to explode/break apart a drop shadow filter into the shape it forms. I mean, I need to be able to have a shape (shape object, or another kind of object) that its generated when I apply a drop shadow.

If I break apart the object, the drop shadow disappears.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: But, will that give me a shape?. Also, what other information would you need me to provide?.

Comment: What Dominic said makes the most sense based on the question. It breaks apart the shadow from the object on different layers by changing the fill opacity. What's vague or slightly confusing is your use of 'shape' which is usually used to define a vectorized object. So it's difficult to make the leap of how to make a drop shadow into a shape like you asked. Dominic's method maintains the initial shape, but sets it's fill opacity of that shape to 0%--so the rasterized drop shadow still exists.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I need, a vectorized object that equals what I see in the drop shadow.

Comment: @Artemix rasterized effects can't be made into vectorized objects, they are two fundamentally different things. You can mimic drop shadows with gradients and transparency, but you can't make a drop shadow effect into a shape.

Comment: I see. I found a way thou. I made the shadow in Illustrator and expanded its appearance. When I export that to Flash, I got 2 different objects, and one of them it's a shape. Ty all anyways.

Answer (score 1):

The way i create separate shadow objects is:

1. Duplicate the original object
2. Fill it with a black color
3. Set the opacity(alpha) to about 10% or whatever you prefer

this is the way i handle the shadows i want.